# download file with window.location 'success' function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to download a file by calling my URL with window.location.

And it works as it should, my issue is that, the controller returning the file takes a few seconds, and i would like a spinner until the download is ready.

Like if I had used a AJAX call, then i would just have started the spinner before, and stopped it on 'Success'. Is there a way to do that when i use window.location?

```
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Download")';
    window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Show an animated gif before you set window.location.  Setting window.location, does create a spinner, but it's up to the browser for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation a long time ago, and the solution i did was using Cookie.

Now I found that this guy has posted almost the same thing:

[Show-an-animation-while-waiting-for-a-download](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095434/Show-an-animation-while-waiting-for-a-download-to)

I hope that it will help you and others